# In which folder should I copy the image (JPEG) so that it could be found?

Tags: graphics, external-files

I used the following code to insert a JPEG image in my document but I don't know where exactly should I copy the image so that it'll be found. I know it must be somewhere in the TeX folder, but I still get an error.

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\frame{\titlepage \vspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{Koala.jpg}
\end{center}
```

Comment: In the same directory as the `.tex` file you're writing, should be fine.

Comment: If you want to put your image in a subfolder of your `.tex` file (let's say `images`) then you have to specify the relative path in your `\includegraphics` command: `\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{images/Koala.jpg}`.

Comment: Which error? Are you using `pdflatex`?

Comment: what error (exactly) do you get?

Answer (score 6):

Option `pdftex` for `graphicx` indicates that you are using/want to use `pdflatex` for compiling the LaTeX document. Engine pdfTeX finds its images the same way as it looks for TeX files, it is using the settings of `TEXINPUTS`. This usually includes the current directory. Other directories can be specified in the argument of `\includegraphics` (see Karl Koeller's comment):

```
\includegraphics[...]{images/koala.jpg}
```

Or the directories can be specified in `\graphicspath` (each path needs to be surrounded by curly braces and should end in the directory separator):

```
\graphicspath{{images/}}%
```

and the file can then be specified without directory:

```
\includegraphics[...]{koala.jpg}
```